# Inserting into mysql databse via php always results in crash

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a my_sql database set up. One of the tables called users has some columns, 2 of which are usr (varchar 32) and email (varchar 255). Whenever I try to insert data into this table into these 2 columns (or any other column) via PHP, the table crashes.

This is the analysis from check table

```
mysql> check table users;
+----------------+-------+----------+-------------------------------------------     +
| Table          | Op    | Msg_type | Msg_text                                       |
+----------------+-------+----------+-------------------------------------------     +
| accounts.users | check | warning  | Table is marked as crashed                     |
| accounts.users | check | error    | Size of indexfile is: 4096    Should be: 10240 |
| accounts.users | check | error    | Size of datafile is: 0        Should be: 28    |
| accounts.users | check | error    | Corrupt                                        |
+----------------+-------+----------+-------------------------------------------     +
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

This is the PHP command:

```
$type     = 'testing';
$type     = mysql_real_escape_string($type);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO users(usr,email) VALUES('$type','$type')");
```

Whenever I try to insert into the database from the command line, the table does not crash.

I am stumped as to why this is happening.

Comment: What does "the table crashes" mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just reinstalled WAMP, and it started working. Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 3):

Run die() after your query and see what the mysql error is, if it is mysql issue:

```
mysql_query(' ... ') or die(mysql_error());
```

the error should be pointing you to your problem.

Comment: Take into consideration that this is a very dangerous proposal, if you forget to remove this line afterwards you'll be exposing code to the end user

Comment: Right, but for debugging purposes only.

Answer (score 2):

Improving mavili's answer, I think it's better to do:

```
if(!mysql_query($SQL)) {
    error_log(mysql_error());
}
```

error_log can write the information on a more secure way. see [the manual for error_log](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php) for more details

Answer (score 1):

`mysql_real_escape_string()` returns the escaped string, or `FALSE` on error. If it returns `FALSE`, it does not match with your `varchar` datatype.There are two points

A MySQL connection is required before using `mysql_real_escape_string()` otherwise an error of level E_WARNING is generated, and FALSE is returned.

The character set must be set either at the server level, or with the API function `mysql_set_charset()` for it to affect `mysql_real_escape_string()`